# str_replace (or preg_replace?) accepting and keeping accented characters and caps

Tags: php, mysql

I'm in the process of building a French MySQL database for a website which will be containing accented characters and caps at some places. All of this works perfectly.

Now I designed a table showing the content of the database (working perfectly) and I put a search bar on top of it. The SQL Query for the search works as intended (using LIKE, it's case insensitive and treats accented characters like their base letter, which is surprisingly exactly what I want).

Here's my problem: I'd like to highlight all instances of the search directly in the table. I got it partly working with this:

```
str_ireplace($_POST["search"], 
             '<span class="highlight">' . $_POST["search"] . "</span>",
             $row['First_Name']);
```

but these problems occur:

- It changes the caps in my table based on search input
- If the user ignores accented characters (searching for "ecole" while looking for "école"), the search doesn't work

I've been looking for a solution for the past 3 hours without any luck. I started reading about `preg_replace()` but can't seem to find the right way of doing it without writing endless code for each possible accented character by hand. It would be great if I could mimic what the SQL Query does with "LIKE" but in php or something.

Comment: So, to summarize, you want `somefunction("foo âccént bar","accent")="foo <higlight>âccént</highlight> bar"`? It's a good question, I've never had to deal with it from that end...

Comment: For the moment, I can only think of a `preg_replace_callback` with a regex which matches anything with a word boundary on both sides `\b.*?\b`, which checks whether an `iconv` to ascii yields your searchterm, and returns it highlighted, and if not, as-is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you do it, you will always display what the user has input, and indeed PHP will not make the same lenient comparison as a MySQL `LIKE`.

Here is a function I wrote that deals with this problem, including most of the French accented characters.

```
function highlight_substring( $string, $substring )
{
  if( empty( $string ) || empty( $substring ) ) return false;

  $normal = array( 'à', 'é', 'è', 'ê', 'ë', 'î', 'ï', 'ô', 'ò', 'ö', 'û', 'ü', 'ù', 'ç' );
  $flat = array( 'a', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'c' );

  $str = mb_strtolower( $string );
  $str = str_replace( $normal, $flat, $str );

  $sub = mb_strtolower( $substring );
  $sub = str_replace( $normal, $flat, $sub );

  $pos = mb_strpos( $str, $sub );

  if( $pos !== false )
  {
    $var = mb_substr( $string, 0, $pos ).'<span class="highlight">'.mb_substr( $string, $pos, mb_strlen( $substring ) ).'</span>';
    $var .= mb_substr( $string,( bcadd( mb_strlen( $substring ), $pos ) ) );
    $string = $var;
  }

  return $string;
}
```

Feel free to adapt and improve ;)

**Usage**

```
echo highlight_substring( 'Allons à l’école !', 'ecole' ); // user input 'ecole'
echo highlight_substring( 'Allons à l’École !', 'ecole' ); // user input 'ecole'
echo highlight_substring( 'Allons à l’école !', 'Ecole' ); // user input 'Ecole'
```

Will output:

```
Allons à l’<span class="highlight">école</span> !
Allons à l’<span class="highlight">École</span> !
Allons à l’<span class="highlight">école</span> !
```

Comment: Prob. not what OP was looking for: "but can't seem to find the right way of doing it without writing endless code for each possible accented character by hand"

Comment: In fact you don't have an endless list, you just have to account for the whole Unicode set ;) But if OP is dealing only with French language input, that will do the trick. Now if you have a perfect solution, please share, I am truly interested.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Even if your code deals with each accented character separately and that's not what I was looking for, I could use some of it, but I'm affraid it doesn't solve my caps problem...

Comment: Have you tried it? Check new usage examples, I'm sure it deals with caps but maybe I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: Omg I'm sorry, it works like a charm! Now is there a way to make the function display the original string if the search is unsuccessful? It just returns nothing if it's the case right now. (searching for "abc" in the string "Allons à l'école" returns ""). There is another problem, it just highlights the first instance of the search in the string... I'd like it to highlight all of them if possible...

Comment: Well, the function always returns `$string` (or haystack if you will) even if the substring (the needle) isn't found in it. In which case the original `$string` is returned untouched (without the `<span>`)

Comment: Hmm... I think I know where the problem comes from... I allow users to write nothing in the search bar to reset the table (like a search for nothing) and it returns nothing... (thank you for your invaluable help btw)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39537/discussion-between-fierceblood-and-sebastien)

Answer (score 1):

here is another variant for PHP 5.3+, it has 1 problem - it actually removes acutes, maybe it will work as partial solution

```
mb_regex_encoding('utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');

$row = array('First_Name' => 'some École text with école ecole end of some text ');

function highlightString($string, $word)
{
    $string = iconv('utf-8', 'ISO-8859-1//IGNORE', Normalizer::normalize($string, Normalizer::FORM_D));
    $word = iconv('utf-8', 'ISO-8859-1//IGNORE', Normalizer::normalize($word, Normalizer::FORM_D));
    return mb_ereg_replace_callback('('.$word.')', function ($m) { return '<span class=\"highlight\">'.$m[0].'</span>';}, $string, 'msri'); // it is not very secure to use data from POST directly
}

echo highlightString($row['First_Name'], 'école') . " <br>\n";
echo highlightString($row['First_Name'], 'ecole'). " <br>\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

Think about to use regex to ignore accents. Something like that:

```
$value = 'É ç école';

echo preg_replace("/&([a-z])[a-z]+;/i", "$1", htmlentities($value));
```